# Why do I get error with this SQL create?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the problem with the following SQL statement:

`create table teamstats (name varchar(10) not null,pos varchar(3) not null,ab numeric(3) not null,hits numberic(4) not null,walks varchar(5) not null,singles varchar(7) not null,doubles varchar7) not null,triples varchar(7) not null,hr numeric(2) not null,so varchar(2) not null);`

and I get:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'numberic(4) not null,walks varchar(5) not nul
>   l,singles varchar(7) not null,doubl' at line 1

Comment: `numberic` is not a data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your SQL:

1. hits numberic(4) not null => numberic is not a valid data type
2. doubles varchar7) not null => you forgot to open the parenthesis in varchar

This is the correct syntax:

```
create table teamstats
(
    name varchar(10) not null,
    pos varchar(3) not null,
    ab numeric(3) not null,
    hits numeric(4) not null,
    walks varchar(5) not null,
    singles varchar(7) not null,
    doubles varchar(7) not null,
    triples varchar(7) not null,
    hr numeric(2) not null,
    so varchar(2) not null
);
```

Here's the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/261351

Comment: What is the key in this table?

Comment: Actually there's no key defined for the table.

Answer (score 2):

**Typo #1**

```
 doubles varchar7)
```

Should be

```
 doubles varchar(7)
```

**Typo #2**

```
numberic
```

should be

```
numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change `numberic` to `numeric`

Answer (score 1):

`numeric` is misspelled as `numberic`; that prevents MySQL from detecting it as a data type, and it doesn't know how to proceed.  You also forgot your open parenthesis in the doubles column:

`doubles varchar(7)`